# my laptop hangs simultaneously while working. Please need help

Tags: 16.04

I am new to Ubuntu. I don't have any coding experience or any hardware or software knowledge. I tried Ubuntu and loved it more than Windows. I have formated my laptop and installed Ubuntu 16.04, and also installed all the updates.

But while working I am facing problems of getting laptop hang several times.

[image]

Please, can you help me out, how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer after searching online.
First I checked my kernel. You can check your kernel in terminal by typing this command `uname -r` my kernel was 4.4 so I updated my kernel to 4.7.5 and it worked. Since I have updated my kernel my problems are resolved. My laptop did not hanged since last 2 days. You can find the below commands to update kernel from 4.4 to 4.7.5.

[My system details and my kernal details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHkji.png)

**For 64-Bit Systems**

$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.5/linux-headers-4.7.5-040705_4.7.5-040705.201609240533_all.deb

$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.5/linux-headers-4.7.5-040705-generic_4.7.5-040705.201609240533_amd64.deb

$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.5/linux-image-4.7.5-040705-generic_4.7.5-040705.201609240533_amd64.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.7.5*.deb linux-image-4.7.5*.deb

sudo reboot

**For 32-bit systems**

$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.5/linux-headers-4.7.5-040705_4.7.5-040705.201609240533_all.deb

$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.5/linux-headers-4.7.5-040705-generic_4.7.5-040705.201609240533_i386.deb

$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.5/linux-image-4.7.5-040705-generic_4.7.5-040705.201609240533_i386.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.7.5*.deb linux-image-4.7.5*.deb

sudo reboot

I hope this helps to newby and others who are facing the same problems like me.